# Sous vide egg white falling apart on cracking

Tags: eggs, sous-vide, egg-whites

[image]

I've been reading the sous vide guide on serious eats where eggs are supposed to come out like [this](https://www.seriouseats.com/images/2013/10/20131004-sous-vide-101-egg-chorizo-corn-crouton-06.jpg) where after sous viding, you poach it briefly to fully set the white. However when cracking my egg, the white simply falls apart completely, leaving the yolk exposed and an impossible to poach egg!

This egg is cooked at 66C for 1.5 hours, which in the guide has a 'fudgy' yolk (how mine comes out).

Comment: some of the question went missing while posting - I've readded the detail

Answer (score 2):

At 66ºC it's possible that the white gets too "crumbly" like yours. I always follow [Dave Arnold's](https://cms.splendidtable.org/sites/default/files/Egg%20Chart%20USE.jpg) guide for egg temperatures and get good results around 64-65ºC.

You should try lowering the temperature to 65 or 65.5ºC, and make sure your eggs are not too old - the older the egg the more "loose whites" (the watery part of the whites) you'll get. It also affects the texture of the rest of the egg.

Comment: Thanks - I was wondering if it might be an issue of older eggs. I notice in the pictures on serious eats that the small amount of loose white falls apart in the same way that all of mine does. I had reasonable results before but I switched supplier (now using free range organic eggs) which I would expect to be superior, but seems like they might have been hanging around a bit.

Comment: There's a number of variables that could make a difference - maybe the eggs are fresh, but the composition is a bit different (water / protein), so you could also try just reducing the time to around 1h and see what happens. Eggs are cheap and 1h is not much time to lose :)